# Open div using nth-child - Jquery

Tags: jquery

is there any way to click on the class "title1" and open "text1" ... click on "title2" and open the "text2"... and so on without using class selector?

```
<nav>
    <div class="title1"> title1 </div>
    <div class="title2"> title2 </div>
</nav>

<div class="text">
    <div class="text1"> text 1 </div>
    <div class="text2"> text 2 </div>
</div>

<script>
$('nav .cada:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
    $('.txt .cada').fadeOut()
    $('.txt .cada:nth-child(1)').fadeIn()
})
$('nav .cada:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
    $('.txt .cada').fadeOut()
    $('.txt .cada:nth-child(2)').fadeIn()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you modify the HTML markup at all or only the JavaScript? Specifically could you add `data-*` attributes?

Comment: i discovery simple answer, check answers  accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i discovery simple answer:

```
<script>
$('nav .cada').click(function(){
    var position = $(this).index() 
    $('.txt .cada').fadeOut()
    $('.txt .cada:nth-child('+position+')').fadeIn()
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*and so on without using **class selector**?*

Just try like this,

```
$("nav div").click(function(){ 
var xTest = $(this).parent().next().find('div');
xTest.fadeOut();
xTest.eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jS84G/)

Comment: I used a class to explain. The structure is not this (I used the structure is more complex, I can not get the element .parent ). I once used the: nth-child but I do not remember how ....

Answer (score 1):

```
$("nav div").on("click", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div.text").children("div").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/VnHG4/

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
$('nav div').click(function(){
    $('.text div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rJRYu/).

Though I'm unsure if you want to avoid using *all* class-selectors, which this doesn't (the inner chain within the `click()` handler, uses one). If, however, *all* classes must be avoided:

```
$('nav div').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().children().hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rJRYu/1/).

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: I used a class to explain. The structure is not this (I used the structure is more complex, I can not get the element .parent ). I once used the: nth-child but I do not remember how ....

Answer (score 0):

`nth-` selectors will not respect the classes whatsoever, so even if you write

```
nav .txt:nth-child(3) {
   /* this won't select 3rd element nested inside nav having class .txt */
}
```

So what you are trying is not possible though using CSS only selector, not aware if jQuery has similar

Comment: I used a class to explain. The structure is not this (I used the structure is more complex, I can not get the element .parent ). I once used the: nth-child but I do not remember how ....